# What collation to use in MySQL for case-insensitive UTF8 matches, but where aee is not the same as áéé?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, utf-8

I have a bunch of `LONGTEXT` fields in my database that uses "Table Default" collation.

The table's collation is "utf8 - default collation".

I just started using MySQL so I'm guessing "utf8 - default collation" means the tables gets its value from some global variable, probably defined in my.ini?

How do change this value, using MySQL workbench 6.0? In Options File > General there is a field named "collation-server", am I supposed to write something there?

I want `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field='abc'`; to NOT find `'ábc'` but it SHOULD find `'ABc'`.

I have many, many tables with "utf8 - default collation", if I can't change something in my.ini to change this value is there some other way of changing all of them? Would save me a lot of trouble doing this manually for hundreds of tables (auto-created from a different type of database, that's why I have so many tables even though I just started using MySQL).

Comment: You can change the database collation using `alter database`:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-database.html You can check the default collation using `show variables where variable_name in ('collation_database')`

Comment: How do I do that with the graphical user interface? I'm using Workbench 6.0, I don't know how to send any ALTER commands to MySQL manually.

Comment: Just found something in status and system variables > system variables > filter "collation". Three variables: collation_connection, collation_database, collation_server. All of them are "utf8_general_ci". I guess there is where I should make changes? Question now is to what?

Comment: All I can find is utf8_bin, but that is case sensitive and I need case insensitivity. Please tell me this is not another flaw in MySQL? Surely case insenitive matching must exist but where a does not equal á?